# Does Content Type text/json have security implications?

Tags: ajax, json, http, xss, content-type

Should I use text/plain instead. Or is text/json actually going to turn out the same when it comes to cross-site security.

Either way, the content will be valid JSON, I just want to make sure I am right about the Content-Type header.

Comment: The correct content type would be application/json

Comment: @Musa, to wit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no security considerations affecting the choice of mime type for the request answer. Note that the proper mime type for JSON is application/json.

Comment: I recommend you read the book The Tangled Web. It explains content sniffing in detail.

Comment: Don't speak up from the soapbox. I read the Tangled Web. I still stand by my assertion that the content of the HTTP content header poses no security considerations. Whatever you can exploit with mime-type application/json you can exploit with text/plain.

Comment: In general or only in this specific scenario? (I don't understand what you mean by your first sentence, but sorry if I somehow offended you)

Comment: Btw. here is an example that seems to contradict your statement that "whatever you can exploit with mime-type application/json you can exploit with text/plain": http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/research/json/testbench.html

Answer (score 1):

yes, there are security implications. Browsers - especially IE - will often second guess the content type. The reasoning is that some time back, servers delivered everything as the same content type so browsers had to make guesses to display things correctly.
Text/plain is notorious for content sniffing (second guessing). If your json contains html inside some of the values, there is a chance that if you open the url directly in the browser, the browser will determine that its HTML and render it. This could lead to XSS.

Comment: This is a common myth and as myths usually go, it is false. The Microsoft reference for mime type detection is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Note, from that document that: a) text/plain is never rendered as HTML in the restricted zone; and b) Unknown mime types are never guessed. This is the behavior all the way back from IE6SP2, launched eight years ago. text/json either is handled as json or handled as an unknown type. It's XSS safe.

Comment: I see this discussion popping up in forums from time to time. Random example from 2011: http://www.highdots.com/forums/html/ie-ignores-text-plain-again-299596.html

Comment: I set up a testbed a while back, which indicates that at least IE9 will treat text/plain as HTML under some circumstances: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/research/json/testbench.html